# List of configuration file limitations for LWC in a managed package

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package

When trying to upgrade exposed LWC in a managed package I have faced the following limitations related to their configuration file.

-You can not remove/rename a previous existing property.

-You can not change the type (f.i: from Integer to String) of a previous existing property.

-You can not remove requiredness of a previous existing property.

I understad the first 2 of them and actually they make sense. However, about the 3rd one, I had some properties with `required="true"` that I changed to `required="false"` and are not reporting errors. The curious thing is the error I am receiving is when changing a property from `required="false"` to `"required="true"`. I find this strange since the problem seems to be just the opposite of what the error message is saying:

> You can’t remove requiredness for the property tag named 'dummyProperty' specified in targetConfig lightning__RecordPage. The component is part of a managed package.

I would appreciate some clarifications around this and, besides, if someone could provide a list of all these kind of limitations I would find that really usefull since I did not find any detailed documentation about that.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug as per me in the manageability rules in the salesforce packaging module or this behavior is not well documented.

You can raise a case for this!

What are Manageability rule?

> Manageability rules are there in place to make sure you do not break the subscriber when your subscribers upgrade a Managed Package.

Most of these rules are documented in the ISV guide in sections below

- [Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm)
- [Components available in the Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)
- [Special Behaviours for the components in packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm)

Looks like the behavior you have is either a bug or it should be documented in the special [behaviors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm) section.

For now, one way to get away with the error is using a **default** value to the config parameter

```
<property name="dummyProperty" required="true" type="String" default="test"></property>
```

Comment: Hi Mohith - Do we have a Known Issue around this so we can track? This is troubling at far greater length, even though we have not packaged and one developer accidently added a new property in our component and now we can't remove this property, even though No Package Upload/Release happened after adding property to LWC.